# Modern Warfare 3 Crashes on Launch: How can I get it running?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When I attempt to launch any part of Modern Warfare Three on my PC through Steam, it crashes immediately, and this happens (multiplayer as example):

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   iw5mp.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  4eb37b9f
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_e8ad
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   003e0000
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  5129
Additional Information 1:   e8ad
Additional Information 2:   e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863
Additional Information 3:   e8ad
Additional Information 4:   e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863
```

When I run the exe's directly from the game directory, the splash screen appears and says that Steam must be running, even when it is.

Is there anything I can do to get this running?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got Steam to check the integrity of your MW3 game cache? Go to the game's properties and hit "Verify Integrity of Game Cache...", this will search for and re-download anything that's modified/corrupt/etc. If that doesn't help, then you have deeper problems... :/

Comment: @DMA57361 Yeah I tried that method - didn't resolve it, sadly. I know that DX doesn't function in Safe Mode, but I went in anyway to see how far I got. I got farther than normal boot, so now I'm just trying to isolate what I can actually stop to make it work! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Oh well. I guess all the usual advice about updating drivers, DX and all that applies, but it sounds like you're covering those already.

Comment: I'm tempted to go as far as installing Windows on another partition and seeing if it will work on a clean install w/drivers - if so, I've got some hunting to do.

Comment: All I can say is that IW is not very interested in helping the users who experience this issue. I cannot play the game since 2 years, and the support plays unknowing of the issue and refers to the most common fixes like "have nvidia control panel in the background" or "disable your firewall/antivirus" (wtf?). The game also freezes when you try to change any in-game graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Steam's options, disabling the in-game overlay means the game now functions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd need to contact IW and give them the debug information, as only they would know what those debug codes mean. This could be done via the forums.

Otherwise you could try to repair it via Steam (redownload/repair).

Comment: Please read the first line of the question. He's mentioning he's running it `through Steam`.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I missed that... just commented on him running it via the exe directly from the game directory. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to disable Steam's in-game overlay - it's caused me trouble with other games, too.